# How to run react project after installing dependencies from package.json

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I'm unable to run the react project that was cloned from github.

After cloning, the steps for running the project locally are:

1. Install dependencies from package.json : `npm install && cd doc && npm install`
2. To run the documentation page in your local server : `npm run docs:dev`

I have already tried adding the line in package.json as - "start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js" in "scripts" which showed an error. 
The file package.json was without the "start" before, and I later added it.

This is my package.json file with only "scripts" part:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js",
    "docs:dev": "cd doc && npm run develop",
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist components && npm run lint:fix",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.prod.js",
    "lint": "eslint ./ --ext .jsx --ext .js && echo \"eslint: no lint errors!\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint ./ --ext .jsx --ext .js --fix && echo \"eslint: all errors fixed!\"",
    "test": "nyc mocha --require @babel/register --require jsdom-global/register --require test/testSetup.js --require test/ignoreStyles.js 'lib/**/*.test.js'",
    "coverage": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov > coverage.lcov && codecov",
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release"
  },
```

The error I'm getting when adding the line in "scripts"
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js" is:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\config
\webpack.dev.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\node_modu
les\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:133:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\node_module
s\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:135:6)
    at C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\node_modules\webpack-cli\b
in\convert-argv.js:142:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\node_modul
es\webpack-cli\bin\convert-argv.js:140:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\node_m
odules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:92:55)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-lite-ui@1.0.2 start: `webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.
dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-lite-ui@1.0.2 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pranav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-15T07_57_27
_526Z-debug.log
```

This is webpack.config.js file

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
   mode: 'development',
});
```

I'm expecting the project should run with npm run start, but I'm getting this error.

Comment: What's the error and stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: Can you post config/webpack.dev.js?

Comment: Thanks for the response... I've edited the above post with the error included

Comment: you posted webpack.config.js. You should look for webpack.dev.js since that's what's referenced in the script

Comment: Sorry by mistakely posted webpack.config.js... I don't have webpack.dev.js file

Answer (score 0):

It is also clearly written that you do not have access to the configuration file. See if you have it `webpack.dev.js`

> Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\Pranav\Documents\GitHub\react-lite-ui\config
>   \webpack.dev.js'

Comment: OK... Can you please see the steps that I have mentioned in the post for installing the dependencies from package.json. I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

Your npm start is incorrect, use the following.

```
 "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack.dev.js",
```

--config=config/webpack.dev.js is incorrect.

Comment: I tried after editing "start", but, getting same error. Can you please see the steps that I have mentioned in the post. I didn't get it

Comment: @Pranav bhai, did you edit the --config to the one above?

Comment: yes I edited and also copied the line that you posted but getting the same error... I think I'am doing some silly mistake... Can you please see the steps above in the post that I've mentioned

Comment: can you update your question with the content of the webpack.dev.js ?
codebrahma's react-lite-ui works out of the box, although not in dev mode.

Comment: Actually I've added "start" in "scripts" which was not available when I cloned the project. Well, the question is how to install dependencies from package.json, which is above in the step 1 mentioned. It says... npm install && cd doc && npm install. I'am stuck in this step

Comment: I also tried to do the same thing, running npm install doesn't create doc folder.One of the command expects the contributor to be either on a linux or a mac machine, I'm talking about the prebuild. edit the pre-build to "npm run lint:fix" and then run `npm run build`. it should work ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I'll go through it again and give a try

Comment: I'am contributing to Codebrahma react-lite-ui project, if possible can you visit the site and follow the steps. Run it in your local machine... If successful, please show me

Comment: @Pranav, try getting in touch with the guys who contributed to that project. Perhaps first thing you'd want to contribute to is to work on the documentation, they'd be better help than me.